# Why aerich init-db throw an tortoise.exceptions.Configuration error: DB configuration not initialised?

Tags: python, tortoise-orm

I have to run a project using aerich and tortoise to work with postgresql. The model files are located in the project root, in the models.py file. The configuration is in the root of the project, in the settings.py file. I run `aerich init -t settings.TORTOISE_ORM` and it works fine, creating an empty migrations/models folder.

But when I then run `aerich init-db` I get the error tortoise.exception.ConfigurationError: DB configuration not initialised. Make sure to call Tortoise.in it with a valid configuration before attempting to create connections.
My TORTOISE_ORM:

```
TORTOISE_ORM = {
    "connections": {"default": db_url},
    "apps": {
        "models": {
            "models": ["app.models", "aerich.models"],
            "default_connection": "default",
        },
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. try delete 'migrations' folder
2. delete tables in your database
3. make sure your 'app.models'path does exist

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).